# PreparedStatement equivalent

Tags: java, string

As for SQL queries we have preparedStatement object which gets compiled at compile time and we could set the wildcard(? in this case) with a value at run time.

Is there an equivalent way of achieving in Java for non-SQL work like for example consider StringFormat as a hypothetical class:

```
StringFormat sf = new StringFormat("ams_?_xyz);
List<String> Codes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
for(Code c: Codes) {
  sf.set(1, c);
  String str = sf.getString();
  // do something
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: So, if I get you, you need to have template-like strings and replace parameters in it. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: So could you give us example input with the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the static [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method:

```
String template = "aws_%s_xyz";
List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));

for(String code : codes){
    String str = String.format(template, code);
}
```

The `"%s"` is like the questionmark `?` in prepared statements.

Comment: `String#format` doesn't receive a `List` as argument.

Comment: Yes, that was so obvious.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am sorry, but my code doesn't call `String.format` with a `List`, that's why I am iterating over `codes` in the for loop

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am not really sure, but OP seems to look exactly for something like this, a "template-for-replacement" inside a loop, if not then the answer from YCF_L may be the one he's looking for

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is `String.format()`:

```
System.out.println(String.format("output %s %s", "a", "b")); // "output a b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)), which look

```
public static String format​(String format, Object... args)
```

This will take a String and a varargs, your code can be :

```
List<String> codes = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
String someString = "ams_%s_xyz";
someString = String.format(someString, codes.toArray());
```

This will return :

```
ams_a_xyz
    ^
```

It will take one by one from your array and replace it in your String, if you have for example :

```
String someString = "ams_%s_xyz__%s";
                         ^^      ^^
```

this will return :

```
ams_a_xyz__b
    ^      ^
```

And so on